# Increase height of div and only have divs underneath it move down, not whole row

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a project where a div's height grows upon click, and I want only the divs underneath that one to move down instead of the whole row...

Right now I have the divs growing in height upon click, but can't figure out how to properly set it up so that the whole row underneath doesnt move down.

[My Codepen](https://codepen.io/Finches/pen/mqgmNX)

```
.section-container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.job-title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #444;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.job-title-container {
  position: relative;
}

.job-information-container {
  background: #888;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  display: none;
}

.job-information-container p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.job-plus-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 15px);
  bottom: -webkit-calc(0% - 15px);
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  bottom: calc(0% - 15px);
  width: 30px;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.to-open {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-vdeg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.to-close {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

Any help?

Comment: You have one entire row of 6 divs, create 3 coulmns with 2 divs in each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it 3 columns and put the ones you want to stack together

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJNRpO

```js
$('.job-title-container').click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
  if ($(this).children('.job-plus-icon').hasClass('to-close')) {
    $(this).children('.job-plus-icon').removeClass('to-close').addClass('to-open');
  } else {
    $(this).children('.job-plus-icon').removeClass('to-open').addClass('to-close');
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
}

.section-container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.job-title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #444;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.job-title-container {
  position: relative;
}

.job-information-container {
  background: #888;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  display: none;
}

.job-information-container p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.job-plus-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 15px);
  bottom: -webkit-calc(0% - 15px);
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  bottom: calc(0% - 15px);
  width: 30px;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.to-open {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-vdeg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.to-close {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-container">
<div class="row">
  
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 job-container">
    
    <div class="job-title-container">
      <h1 class="job-title">Job Title</h1>
      <img class="job-plus-icon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/60/60740.png"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="job-information-container">
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use .</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="job-title-container">
      <h1 class="job-title">Job Title2</h1>
      <img class="job-plus-icon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/60/60740.png"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="job-information-container">
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 job-container">
    
    <div class="job-title-container">
      <h1 class="job-title">Job Title3</h1>
      <img class="job-plus-icon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/60/60740.png"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="job-information-container">
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="job-title-container">
      <h1 class="job-title">Job Title4</h1>
      <img class="job-plus-icon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/60/60740.png"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="job-information-container">
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>

  
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 job-container">
    
    <div class="job-title-container">
      <h1 class="job-title">Job Title5</h1>
      <img class="job-plus-icon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/60/60740.png"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="job-information-container">
      <p>Many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="job-title-container">
      <h1 class="job-title">Job Title6</h1>
      <img class="job-plus-icon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/60/60740.png"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="job-information-container">
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident.</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>

  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.job-container` is positioned relatively, so all the `.job-container` divs will grow to fill the space available.  When you expand the top middle one (for instance), the others in that "row" (not the actual `div.row`) expand by the same amount to fill the newly-available space.

If you create 3 columns with 2 `job-container`s in each column, you should be able to achieve what you want- but if you have twenty `job-container`s instead of six, you're going to have to manually determine which `job-container` goes in which div.